# How do I detect when Emscripten's generated .js finishes loading the wasm so I can run my JS functions which call it?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I'm using Emscripten to compile some C code to WebAssembly. This is the final emcc call in my Makefile:

```
emcc $(CFLAGS) iva.a -o iva.js
```

Which works as intended and generates a .js file and a .wasm file. The JS is loaded into my HTML page as follows:

```
<script src="../dist/iva.js">
```

And it loads and instantiates the WebAssembly code `iva.wasm` properly. This message appears in the console soon after I load the page:

```
Fetch finished loading: GET "http://localhost:6931/dist/iva.wasm".
```

Which I take to mean that my WebAssembly is loaded through a fetch() and, perhaps pending some processing, I can access my functions through the console:

```
Module._init_display_system()
```

And get the return values. This holds true and everything works.

Clearly, I should be able to do this through a script as well. However, I can't see a way to only run a function *after* my WebAssembly has been instantiated. I get the feeling that I'm missing something rather obvious.

Anyway, how do I do this?

Comment: can you show the content of iva.js

Comment: All wasm tutorials show that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API or https://webassembly.org/getting-started/js-api/ . `fetch`-`instantiate`-usetheexports is usually chained via `Promise`s, emcc-generated stub most certainly does the same.

Comment: @tevemadar so then do I edit the Emscripten generated JS to call my code when instantiation succeeds?

Comment: @tevemadar never mind, turns out the answer is using Module['onRuntimeInitialized'].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Module['onRuntimeInitialized']`.

```
Module['onRuntimeInitialized'] = function() {
       console.log("wasm loaded ");
       var x=Module.ccall("doubleIt","number",["number"],[20]);
       alert(x);
    }
```

You have used emsdk, there are online WASM compilers like Wasmfiddle. Find [my github repo](https://github.com/sudhakar3697/WebAssembly-Sample) useful for both the methods.

Answer (score 7):

While the two solutions of [Sudhakar RS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58256067/11942268) and [Anil8753](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59345430/11942268) are totally fine, I want to add, that you have to execute this approach **before** you load your WebAssembly. Otherwise it might be too late to catch the event.

Besides that, there is another approach, which uses promises. If you add

```
-s MODULARIZE=1 -s 'EXPORT_NAME="createMyModule"'
```

as options when compiling with `emcc`, your resulting `.js` will contain the function `createMyModule`. This function will return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolves as soon as your WebAssembly code is ready to use. Example usage:

In your HTML, add your WebAssembly as you already did:

```html
<script src="../dist/iva.js">
```

In your js, call the function and after the promise resolved, you are good to go:

```js
createMyModule().then(MyModule => {
  console.log('WebAssembly loaded!');
  // Access your functions (if bound by Embind):
  console.log(MyModule.getSomething());
});
```

Comment: This solution goes very well with web workers, where you want to start the computation once the main thread posts a message. 
`
self.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    createMyModule().then(Module => {
      self.postMessage(doSomethingWithModule(Module));
    }
`
Otherwise you'll have to post a message TO the main thread once the WASM is loaded to let it know that it's ready for commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>
    var Module = {
      onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
         console.log('module loaded');
      }
    };
  </script>
```