# Problem with Emscripten with MINIMAL_RUNTIME

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I am new to emscripten, so this may be an easy one to answer for others. I can't get access to my C functions. Here is the setup:

Simple C file square.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE 
double square(double x){
    return x*x;
}
```

Content of ready.js:

```
ready = function () {
    startup();
}
```

startup is a function that I added to square.html to know when everything is ready.

Emcc command Line:

```
emcc square.c -DNDEBUG -s MINIMAL_RUNTIME -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s INVOKE_RUN=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=web,worker -s MODULARIZE=1 -s SUPPORT_ERRNO=0 --pre-js ./ready.js -s EXPORT_NAME=wasmMod -o square.html
```

output is as expected: square.html, square.js, square.wasm

Everything runs in Chrome as expected, startup is called. Now I want to access the square function:

```
function startup(){
  console.log('startup called');
  let y = _square(2);
  console.log(`square: ${y}`);
}
```

this gives me an error: "VM291:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _square is not defined"
If I use

```
let y = wasmMod._square(2);
```

instead, I get
"square.js:783 TypeError: wasmMod._square is not a function"

I have tried a lot of things and searched the web, but I can't seem to find the error.
If I remove -s MODULARIZE=1, I can call _square(2) without problems, however, in that case wasmMod doesn't hold anything, all variables and functions are in Global context, which is something I want to avoid.
Once it works I want to embed this part into a larger JS project using ES6 modules, so my goal is to keep everything related to emscripten in one module.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

2020/10/27: added script from html file:

```
// Depending on the build flags that one uses, different files need to be downloaded
// to load the compiled page. The right set of files will be expanded to be downloaded
// via the directive below.
  function binary(url) { // Downloads a binary file and outputs it in the specified callback
      return new Promise((ok, err) => {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', url, true);
        x.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        x.onload = () => { ok(x.response); }
        x.send(null);
      });
    }
  
  function script(url) { // Downloads a script file and adds it to DOM
    return new Promise((ok, err) => {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.src = url;
      s.onload = () => {
        var c = wasmMod;
        delete wasmMod;
        ok(c);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    });
  }
  Promise.all([script('square.js'), binary('square.wasm')]).then((r) => {
  // Detour the JS code to a separate variable to avoid instantiating with 'r' array as "this" directly to avoid strict ECMAScript/Firefox GC problems that cause a leak, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1540101
  var js = r[0];
  js({ wasm: r[1] });
});
```

2020/10/27: added some content from square.js:

```
var wasmMod=
function(wasmMod) {
  wasmMod = wasmMod || {};

var Module = wasmMod;

...lots of javascript follows ...

var imports = {
 "env": asmLibraryArg,
 "wasi_snapshot_preview1": asmLibraryArg
};

var _square, _fflush, stackSave, stackRestore, stackAlloc, _emscripten_get_sbrk_ptr, _sbrk;

if (!Module["wasm"]) throw "Must load WebAssembly Module in to variable Module.wasm before adding compiled output .js script to the DOM";

WebAssembly.instantiate(Module["wasm"], imports).then(function(output) {
 var asm = output.instance.exports;
 _square = asm["square"];
 _fflush = asm["fflush"];
 stackSave = asm["stackSave"];
 stackRestore = asm["stackRestore"];
 stackAlloc = asm["stackAlloc"];
 _emscripten_get_sbrk_ptr = asm["emscripten_get_sbrk_ptr"];
 _sbrk = asm["sbrk"];
 wasmTable = asm["__indirect_function_table"];
 initRuntime(asm);
 ready();
}).catch(function(error) {
 console.error(error);
});


  return {}
}
```

Comment: Using the `MODULARIZE` option, you can access and call your functions like in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941727/11942268).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Thomas. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I can't see a promise being returned.
Here is the structure of the js file:
var wasmMod=
function(wasmMod) {
  wasmMod = wasmMod || {};
...lots of js..

  return {}
}

I will add the script on the html page in my initial post for you to see how this gets invoked.

Comment: In your case `wasmMod` is the function that will return a Promise. You might also check your quoting on `EXPORT_NAME...`...

Comment: I added the important part of square.js above.  wasmMod ends with "return {}".
It looks like the EXPORT_NAME is working, looking at the beginning of that file. 
So the function exits by returning an empty object, and later the ready function is called from within the instantiate call. Thanks again for looking at this.
PS: this is all code generated by emcc without changes except for the function startup, which does nothing.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Instead of trying to understand 1000 lines of generated JavaScript glue code, just trust the [documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions) and do what it says. I can confirm that it works. Use it or lose it. Over and out.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. I'm not ignoring your suggestion, and I am grateful for your help. I tried your suggestion. Here is what I used (after including the script at the top of the html file):
let res = binary('square.wasm')
.then(wasm => {
  wasmMod({wasm: wasm}).then(MyModule => {
    console.log('WebAssembly loaded!');
    // Access your functions (if bound by Embind):
    console.log(MyModule.square(3));
  });
});
This gives me an error:
square.html:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: wasmMod(...).then is not a function
    at square.html:44
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing, and I have a working solution now based on the recommendation that @Thomas provided. Thanks again for that.
However, I got it to work only if I drop the MINIMAL_RUNTIME flag.

The difference:
**without MINIMAL_RUNTIME**:

```
emcc square.c -DNDEBUG  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 -s INVOKE_RUN=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=web,worker -s MODULARIZE=1 -s SUPPORT_ERRNO=0 -s "EXPORT_NAME='wasmMod'" -o square.html
```

Call from square.html:

```
let res = binary('square.wasm')
.then(wasm => { wasmMod({wasm: wasm})
.then(MyModule => { 
  console.log('WebAssembly loaded!');
  console.log(MyModule._square(3));
});
});
```

MyModule contains everything I need. I can use my wasm functions without problems.

Now **with MINIMAL_RUNTIME**:

```
emcc square.c -DNDEBUG -s MINIMAL_RUNTIME -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 -s INVOKE_RUN=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=web,worker -s MODULARIZE=1 --pre-js ./ready.js -s SUPPORT_ERRNO=0 -s "EXPORT_NAME='wasmMod'" -o square.html -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['getValue','setValue']"
```

Using the same calling sequence in the HTML file gives an error:

```
square.html:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: wasmMod(...).then is not a function at square.html:44
```

I can't get this to work like the version without MINIMAL_RUNTIME. Inside function `ready()` I have access to _square() inside the wasmMod closure, however, outside that closure no module exists that I can access. wasmMod points to the js function only, not to a module.
I expect the error to be on my side, however, I can't spend any more time on this, so I will for now cruise with the full version.